# Android: Parsing a JSON array Inside of Another JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm new to JSON parsing and I've been having trouble wrapping my head around JSONArrays and JSONObjects and how to navigate through each. My application parses JSON data and displays it in an recycler view. The JSON response contains three JSON arrays that I want to get data from. The Offices, Officials, and Address arrays. The problem here is that the address array is inside of the officials array and I don't know how to parse that data. The application works fine for some pieces of data, but when I try to parse data from the address array, I get an error from the logcat. Here is the entire JSON response

```
   {
 "normalizedInput": {
  "line1": "2613 Irvington Avenue",
  "city": "San Bernardino",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip": "92407"
 },
 "offices": [
  {
   "name": "President of the United States",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfState",
    "headOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States Senate",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorUpperBody"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States House of Representatives CA-31",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorLowerBody"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Governor",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lieutenant Governor",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "City Treasurer"
  },
  {
   "name": "Mayor"
  },
  {
   "name": "City Attorney"
  },
  {
   "name": "City Clerk"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sheriff-Coroner"
  },
  {
   "name": "Auditor-Controller-Treasurer-Tax Collector"
  },
  {
   "name": "District Attorney"
  },
  {
   "name": "Assessor-Clerk-Recorder"
  },
  {
   "name": "San Bernardino County Superior Court Judge"
  },
  {
   "name": "CA State Assembly District 40"
  },
  {
   "name": "CA State Senate District 23"
  },
  {
   "name": "Board of Supervisors, District 5"
  },
  {
   "name": "Secretary of State"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Treasurer"
  },
  {
   "name": "Attorney General"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Superintendent of Public Instruction"
  },
  {
   "name": "State Controller"
  },
  {
   "name": "Insurance Commissioner"
  }
 ],
 "officials": [
  {
   "name": "Donald J. Trump",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/PE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "potus"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Pence",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/VPE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "VP"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Kamala D. Harris",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "112 Hart Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-3553"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "KamalaHarris"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "UC0XBsJpPhOLg0k4x9ZwrWzw"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Dianne Feinstein",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "331 Hart Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-3841"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://bioguide.congress.gov/bioguide/photo/F/F000062.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "SenatorFeinstein"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "SenFeinstein"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "SenatorFeinstein"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Pete Aguilar",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1223 Longworth House Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20515"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 225-3201"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://aguilar.house.gov/sites/aguilar.house.gov/files/styles/congress_image_medium/public/wysiwyg_uploaded/Headshot_0.jpg?itok=LSt7qkOV",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "reppeteaguilar"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "RepPeteAguilar"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "UCIXCmfuRWrbgdTw257_lxJQ"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "UCxwbFLOlKDsXrwizV5jah7g"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Edmund G. Brown Jr.",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "c/o State Capitol",
     "line2": "Suite 1173",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 445-2841"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+JerryBrown"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "jerrybrown"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "JerryBrownGov"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Gavin Newsom",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "State Capitol",
     "line2": "Suite 1114",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 445-8994"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://www.ltg.ca.gov/images/newsimages/i2.png",
   "emails": [
    "gavin@gavinnewsom.com"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+GavinNewsom"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "GavinNewsom"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "gavinnewsom"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "David C. Kennedy",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "300 N. \"D\" Street",
     "line2": "2nd Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92418"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 384-5022"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "R. Carey Davis",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "300 N. \"D\" Street - 6th Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92418"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 384-5133"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "MayorCareyDavis"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Gary D. Saenz",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "300 N. \"D\" Street",
     "line2": "6th Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92418"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 384-5355"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "Attorney@sbcity.org"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Georgeann \"Gigi\" Hanna",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "300 N. \"D\" Street",
     "line2": "2nd Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92418"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 384-5002"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "John McMahon",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "655 East Third Street",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92415"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(760) 956-5001"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "paffairs@sbcsd.org"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "sbcountysheriff"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "sbcountysheriff"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Oscar Valdez",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "222 W. Hospitality Lane",
     "line2": "4th Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92415"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 382-7014"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Michael Ramos",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "303 West 3rd Street",
     "line2": "6th Floor",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92415"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 382-3669"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "SanBernardinoCountyDistrictAttorney"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "sbcountyda"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Bob Dutton",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "First Floor",
     "line2": "222 W. Hospitality Lane",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92415"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(855) 732-2575"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Denise Trager Dvorak",
   "party": "Nonpartisan"
  },
  {
   "name": "James C. Ramos",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "PO BOX 942849",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "94249"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic Party",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 319-2040"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Morrell",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "STATE CAPITOL",
     "line2": "1303 10TH ST RM 3056",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 919-7731"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://senate.ca.gov/sites/senate.ca.gov/files/senator_photos/morrell-mike.jpg",
   "emails": [
    "senator.morrell@senate.ca.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "MikeMorrellGOP"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "MikeMorrellGOP"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Josie Gonzales",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "385 N. Arrowhead Ave.",
     "line2": "5th Fl.",
     "city": "San Bernardino",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "92415"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(909) 387-4565"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "supervisorgonzales"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "SupervisorJosie"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Alex Padilla",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1500 11th Street,",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 653-7244"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "secretary.padilla@sos.ca.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "CaliforniaSOS"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "CASOSvote"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "John Chiang",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "P.O. Box 942809",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "94209"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 653-2995"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "STONewsroom"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Xavier Becerra",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Office of the Attorney General",
     "line2": "1300 \"I\" Street",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 445-9555"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "XavierBecerra"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "AGBecerra"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Tom Torlakson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1430 N Street,",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 319-0800"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "superintendent@cde.ca.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "CAEducation"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "cadepted"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Betty T. Yee",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "P.O. Box 942850",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "94250"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 445-2636"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "137732083043662"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "CAController"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Dave Jones",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "300 Capitol Mall,",
     "city": "Sacramento",
     "state": "CA",
     "zip": "95814"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic",
   "phones": [
    "(916) 492-3500"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "108233445289196913395"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "insurancecagov"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "CDINews"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Parse function:

```
  //fetch json data from Civic API
    private void getData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    //first loop through offices array. Retrieve officeName value
                    JSONArray officesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("offices");        //One array for offices
                    JSONArray officialsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("officials");    //one array for officials
                    for (int i = 0; i < officesArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonOffices = officesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonOfficials = officialsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonAddress = jsonOfficials.getJSONObject("address");
                        String line1 = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("address").getString("line1");
                        String city = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("address").getString("city");
                        String state = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("address").getString("state");
                        String zip = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("address").getString("zip");
                        if (jsonOfficials.has("photoUrl")) {
                            Reps reps1 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("party"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("photoUrl"),
                                    line1,
                                    city,
                                    state,
                                    zip
                            );

                            repList.add(reps1);
                        } else {
                            Reps reps2 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                    jsonOfficials.getString("party"),
                                    line1,
                                    city,
                                    state,
                                    zip
                           );

                            repList.add(reps2);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter = new RepRvAdapter(repList, getApplicationContext());
                    myrv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

The logcat error says that the JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
[image]

I understand why I am getting this error. It is because I am calling .getJSONObject on a JSON Array, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

EDIT: Added some log tags for troubleshooting. Looks like no value for address is found for Denise Trager Dvorak. This is where the error is. How do I fix it? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `address` is a JSONArray which contains an object with the address information.

So you need to access the first object in the array and get the information from there like this:

```
    //fetch json data from Civic API
private void getData(){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                //first loop through offices array. Retrieve officeName value
                JSONArray officesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("offices");        //One array for offices
                JSONArray officialsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("officials");    //one array for officials
                for (int i = 0; i < officesArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonOffices = officesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject jsonOfficials = officialsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray jsonAddress = jsonOfficials.getJSONArray("address");
                    String line1 = jsonAddress.getJSONObject(0).getString("line1");
                    String city = jsonAddress.getJSONObject(0).getString("city");
                    String state = jsonAddress.getJSONObject(0).getString("state");
                    String zip = jsonAddress.getJSONObject(0).getString("zip");
                    if (jsonOfficials.has("photoUrl")) {
                        Reps reps1 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                jsonOfficials.getString("party"),
                                jsonOfficials.getString("photoUrl"),
                                line1,
                                city,
                                state,
                                zip
                        );

                        repList.add(reps1);
                    } else {
                        Reps reps2 = new Reps(jsonOffices.getString("name"),
                                jsonOfficials.getString("name"),
                                jsonOfficials.getString("party"),
                                line1,
                                city,
                                state,
                                zip
                        );

                        repList.add(reps2);
                    }
                }
                adapter = new RepRvAdapter(repList, getApplicationContext());
                myrv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**EDIT1:**

I have adapted the code to try it locally on my machine with your provided json and everything is working find. Here you can see the images:

[image: Adapted code]

[image: Results]

Could you please log some results in the solution I posted earlier and check if maybe some object don't have an address, or maybe we are missing something else.

Comment: I updated my code but the logcat still returns error: JSONException: No value for address at line 156

Comment: let me try and make some adjustments, I'll post the working code

Comment: I appreciate it! Been stuck on this for a while. Its always between these 2 logcat errors though

Comment: I added some logs to my code. I get the same output, but after the last address "First Floor" i get the error. Ill update with a picture

Comment: Ok. The issue is that the candidate Denise Trager Dvorak doesnt have any address data available

Comment: Ok, so then you would just have to check first if each object has an address before trying to parse it. 
Hope I could be of help and you could mark my answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186326/discussion-between-gabriel-and-drilonreqica).